# Failing to create "flat violin plot" using geom_flat_violin()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use David Robinson's `geom_flat_violin()` to make a plot according to the example in this link: https://gist.github.com/dgrtwo/eb7750e74997891d7c20

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, carat)) +
    geom_flat_violin() +
    coord_flip()
```

If I follow the example I get

> Error in geom_flat_violin() : could not find function "geom_flat_violin"

but when I try to copy in his function code, there are several "unexpected ',' " errors and I don't understand what to copy and what to leave behind. Can anyone help?

Comment: There's one too many parenthesis in the code snippet that was posted. On line 45 change it from `xmax = x + width / 2)` to `xmax = x + width / 2` (without the closing parenthesis) and then it should work.

Comment: The discussion below that code points to a few errors in the code (including stray commas and parentheses). Have you fixed them ?

Comment: Maybe also take a look at the [ggridges](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html) package for more options.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the code listed on the provided link. As the comments in the link suggested, there are some mismatched parenthesis. This can be fixed by removing line 50.

Also, be sure to install the libraries prior to running. This includes the `ggplot2`, `dplyr`, and `plyr`. Typically, they can be installed like so:

```
install.packages( c( "dplyr", "ggplot2", "plyr" ) )
```

I was able to run that code after making the fixes listed above.

```
source( './geom_flat_violin.R' )
ggplot( diamonds, aes( cut, carat ) ) + geom_flat_violin() + coord_flip()
```